# junit spring boot profile properties not being read

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am trring to read a value from the properties file in my junit setup using spring boot.
I can not read the value. Below is my content:-

application-test.properties

```
my.user.name=Amar
```

COnfig file to create beans:

```
@Configuration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Profile("test")
public class RdbmsTestConfig {

    @Value("${my.user.name}")
    private String name;

    @Bean
    public String myString(){
        return "Amar";
    }

    @Bean
    public PropsHolder propsHolder() {
        PropsHolder propsHolder = new PropsHolder();
        propsHolder.setUserName(name);
        return propsHolder;
    }
 }
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RdbmsTestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestRoomService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myString")
    private String myString;

    @Autowired
    private PropsHolder propsHolder;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Test
    public void userTest() {
        Arrays.stream(env.getActiveProfiles()).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println(propsHolder.getUserName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(myString);
        Assert.assertEquals("Amar",myString);
    }
}
```

The value for propsHolder.getUserName comes out to be ${my.user.name}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a base test class that has the required annotations:-

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RdbmsTestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class BastTest { }
```

@ActiveProfiles set the profile to use used, I dont have to mention it in the application.properties file

My test class now extends this:-

```
public class TestRoomService extends BastTest
```

In my RdbmsTestConfig remove @ActiveProfiles annotation.

Answer (score 2):

First remove `@ActiveProfiles("test")` from your class `RdbmsTestConfig`. Then your test just defines the `RdbmsTestConfig` as spring context. As I can see you do not run a real spring boot test. The problem is you do not have any `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` configured in your spring config. So either configure one `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or add `@SpringBootTest` to your test if you have any SpringBootApplication.

Comment: Upvoting this answer as @SpringBootTest was the missing link

Answer (score 0):

I've never used @Profile(), so i'm not sure if that is supposed to do what you want it to do. But I'm always using @PropertySources(), because otherwise, how is the code supposed to know where to look for the properties?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("classpath:core-
test.properties") })
```

Comment: I want to use spring profiles to set up some beans and configuration to run when I test my application. Thanks for the approach that you have suggested. I had already tried this, it works on its own but not with the profiles.